# chaining query with $resource

Tags: angularjs, meanjs, angular-resource, angularjs-ng-resource

I have the following service which uses ngResource to set my syllableCount be clicking a button.

```
 //Words service used to communicate Words REST endpoints
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('words')
    .factory('querywordsService', querywordsService);

  querywordsService.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function querywordsService($resource) {
    return $resource('api/words/?syllableCount=:count', {syllableCount: '@count'},
    {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
})();
```

If the syllableCount button 2 is clicked the query shows the specific word. This is how it looks in the Controller:

```
    $scope.searchCount = function (count) {
      $scope.searchWords = querywordsService.query({count: count});
};
```

Everything works fine! But i need more than syllableCount inside the query. There are at least 4 other parameters that should go inside. If i just chain them like:

```
api/words/?syllableCount=:count&?syllableStructur=:struct ....
```

its not working.

Is there a good way to chain multiple queries like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if i use it like this:

```
    //Words service used to communicate Words REST endpoints
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('words')
  .factory('querywordsService', querywordsService);

  querywordsService.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function querywordsService($resource) {

    var wordsData = $resource('/api/words/?syllableCount=:count&syllableStructur=:struct&frequency=:freq&emphasis=:emph',
    { count: '@count', struct: '@struct', freq: '@freq', emph: '@emph' },
      {
        update: {
          method: 'PUT'
        }
      });

      return {
        wordsData: wordsData
      };
  }
})();
```

in the controller i set the different parameters to the value i need with ng-click from the buttons.